# how to make right cycle

Tags: java, testing

```
private void clickOnTask(String param) {
    TestData.SIZE_OF_TASKS = ts.listOfTasks().allTasks().size();
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= TestData.SIZE_OF_TASKS - 1; i++) {
        if (ts.listOfTasks().allNamesForTask().get(i).getAttribute("title").equals(param)) {
            found = true;
            ts.listOfTasks().allTasks().get(i).click();
        }
    }
    if (found = false) {
        js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('td')[" + TestData.SIZE_OF_TASKS + "].scrollIntoView()");
        TestData.SIZE_OF_TASKS = ts.listOfTasks().allTasks().size();

    }
}
```

I want to 
1)compare all located elements with String param  2) if there are no same , scroll by js and to campare again

*But it compare only first element and then scroll , but I want it to compare the first few located elements , and then do js  *

I tried to continue and brake with marks, but maybe do something wrong...

Comment: Do you want to execute the js only if there are no elements matching with `param` or if there is at least one element that doesn't match?

Comment: this method will find only one element matching with param , i want to scroll for loading next seweral elements.

Comment: yes , if there are no elements matching with param

Comment: i want to match all located with param, and then execute the js

Comment: but my program matching first and execute js

Comment: i should tj do something with for(){  if(){}   }, but dont know what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a flag in order to know whether there are no elements matching `param`.
Outside the for loop you should check this flag to scroll by js only if needed (if no elements at all match with `param`).

```
boolean found = false;

// Compare all located elements
for (int i=0; i<ts.listOfTasks().allTasks().size(); i++) {
    if (ts.listOfTasks().allNamesForTask().get(i).getAttribute("title").equals(param)) {
        found = true;
        ts.listOfTasks().allTasks().get(i).click();
    }
}

// if there are no same, scroll by js
if (!found) {
    TestData.SIZE_OF_TASKS=ts.listOfTasks().allTasks().size();
    js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('td')["+TestData.SIZE_OF_TASKS+"].scrollIntoView()");
    // and to campare again
    // call a method that clear and fill task's list with the new data, then
    clickOnTask(param);
}
```

If after executing the for loop `found` is still `false`, it means that there are no elements at all whose title is `param`, because if there had been at least one, the `if` inside the for loop would have been executed setting `found` to `true`.

By the way, instead of calling several times `ts.listOfTasks().allTasks()` you should put it in a local variable and use such variable (and [enhanced for-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) if possible).

Comment: and how to loop again ?

Comment: You have to call the method containing that code inside the if, where I put the related comment. If you post the whole method I could improve the answer.

Comment: it should be in one method

Comment: Could you please edit your question posting the whole method? Please also take a look at [recursion in java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-recursion)

Comment: Do `js.executeScript()` method updates (or calls something else that update) the task's list? If not, how do you populate such list? What's `ts` variable?

Comment: After `js.executeScript()` you have to empty the task's list and populate it using the new elements, then you can call `clickOnTask(param);` in order to search again.